# Uploading file to S3 Bucket from /tmp/

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I automated my apache http logs to be stored in the tmp directory, which is running the script correctly until moving the file to the tmp directory. Now I have added few more lines of script to move those .tar files to the S3 bucket. When I perform this command manually they are getting moved to the s3 bucket but I do not want to do it everyday since its a daily job and I would want to automate them.

The .tar file is present in the /tmp/ directory when I manually go there and look but the awscl fails to locate to it.

> The error I am getting is : the user provided path does not exist when I run the script.

the lines of code I added were these,

```
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install apache2
sudo ufw allow 'Apache'
sudo systemctl start apache2
myname="abcd"
sudo tar -cvf $myname-httpd-logs-date +'%d%m%Y-%H%M%S'.tar /var/log/apache2/*.log
sudo mv *.tar /tmp/
sudo apt install awscli -y
s3_bucket="s3_test"    
aws s3 \
    cp /tmp/$myname-httpd-logs-$(date +'%d%m%Y-%H%M%S').tar \
    s3://$s3_bucket/$myname-httpd-logs-date +'%d%m%Y-%H%M%S'.tar
```

Can anyone help me out in figuring out why this error has occurred and how to fix it.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdWkA.jpg)

Comment: The error is clear. The file does not exist. Not sure what is not clear about that?

Comment: @Marcin but when I go to the tmp directory I can clearly see that the file is present in it. If I run those commands for s3 manually they are getting moved to the bucket but when I add them to the script I am getting the error as path does not exist.

Comment: "add them to the script" - what script? You haven't showed any.

Comment: bash script.

sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install apache2
sudo ufw allow 'Apache'
sudo systemctl status apache2
sudo systemctl start apache2
sudo systemctl enable apache2
timestamp="date +'%d%m%Y-%H%M%S'"
sudo tar -cvf ${myname}-httpd-logs-${timestamp}.tar /var/log/apache2/*.log
sudo mv *.tar /tmp/
sudo aws s3 \
cp /tmp/${myname}-httpd-logs-${timestamp}.tar \
s3://${s3_bucket}/${myname}-httpd-logs-${timestamp}.tar

Comment: That script does not have the command mentioned in this question.  Please edit your post to include a [mre] of the issue you're encountering.

Comment: I have updated it issue with full script I made.

Comment: Is that the actual command you're running?  It won't create a .tar file, rather it'll try to create a file called "$myname-httpd-logs-date"

Comment: Yeah looks like it. Time stamp is causing the issue. Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be calling datetime multiple times to construct different filenames.  Rather than calling it multiple times, if you call it once, you will ensure that each time you refer to the tar filename, it uses the same name:

```bash
myname="abcd"
target_name=$myname-httpd-logs-`date +'%d%m%Y-%H%M%S'.tar`
sudo tar -cvf $target_name /var/log/apache2/*.log
sudo mv $target_name /tmp/

s3_bucket="s3_test"    
aws s3 \
    cp /tmp/$target_name \
    s3://$s3_bucket/$target_name
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction. The timestamp is hell to deal with. Missed out that each time I call it the file name keeps changing and it messes up my script.

Answer (score 0):

There is not needed `'` in your command in `$(date +'%d%m%Y-%H%M%S)`. It should be:

```
aws s3 \
cp /tmp/$myname-httpd-logs-$(date +%d%m%Y-%H%M%S).tar \
s3://$s3_bucket/$myname-httpd-logs-${timestamp}.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want the unneeded quote

```
aws s3 \
cp /tmp/$myname-httpd-logs-$(date +'%d%m%Y-%H%M%S').tar \
s3://$s3_bucket/$myname-httpd-logs-${timestamp}.tar
```

be sure to close it (the syntax color gives you a clue).